# The Arrow of Time in a Non-Physical Realm

Tags: soft-question, quantum-information, physics, ni.networking-internet

Could there be a logically consistent theory supporting the transmission of non-physical information to a point in time previous to the time it was sent using a computer network (quantum theory, etc)? I'm working on a sci-fi story and need some legit science to back up just such an occurrence - so there's no limit re: real world application.

Comment: Basically reposted [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27243/the-arrow-of-time-in-a-network).

Comment: What is non-physical information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the consequences of such transmission to theoretical computer science (the only aspect of your question that is on-topic here) see Aaronson and Watrous's ["Closed Timelike Curves Make Quantum and Classical Computing Equivalent"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2669).